# C# with DirectX

Tags: c#

i need a coding for sorting the lines which arranged in different order but they had contact each other these lines are stored in list.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us how the lines are stored in the list, and what kind of list.  Are the lines defined by the two endpoints or by a vector?

Comment: ya it is defined by two points and also it is stored any order

Comment: I *think* ratty is talking about geometry, specifically a series of start-end line coords, some of which presumably intersect each other. However, I'm not clear on what 'sorting' might do here - move them along one or other axis? ratty, can you give us a quick example of an input and the output you are looking for?

Comment: take + symbol connecting with each other . phil h your are exactly right i am looking for

Comment: and now how would you "arrange" connected geometry lines?

Comment: i just say example + it is like that it is connecting with series of lines

Answer (score 0):

Or you use a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx), and then you wil have automatically your items sorted, or you use a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) and then your list is linked.

You can implement also your own LinkedList with a method that will return a SortedList from the available LinkedList members.

In order to sort objects in the Sorted List, you will need to implement a comparer ([IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a8xew6.aspx))(a way to tell what object(line in your case) is upper/lower than an other similar one).

Answer (score 0):

"I need an algorithm for sorting lines which are arranged in different order but are making contact with each other. These lines are stored in list."

I think ratty is talking about geometry, specifically a series of start-end line coords, some of which presumably intersect each other.

If ratty means that he has a list of the edges of a polygon, and wants to sort them to get the closed shape, then this would work once translated to c# and using ratty's storage system:

```
from math import sqrt
origpoly = [( (0,0),(7,8) ),
            ( (7,8),(1,2) ),
            ( (1,2),(3,0) ),
            ( (3,0),(0,0) )]
shuffledpoly = [origpoly[2],origpoly[0],origpoly[3],origpoly[1]]

def r(vertex):
    return sqrt(vertex[0]^2 + vertex[1]^2)

# dict of starting vertices, and find starting vertex nearest 0,0
startmap = {}
minstate = ( r(shuffledpoly[0][0]) , 0 )
for idx,pair in enumerate(shuffledpoly):
    startmap[pair[0]] = idx
    thisr = r(pair[0])
    if(thisr<minstate[0]):
    minstate = ( thisr, idx )

# begin with vertex nearest 0,0
sortedpoly = []
coords = shuffledpoly[minstate[1]][0]
for l in shuffledpoly:
    idx = startmap[coords]
    line = shuffledpoly[idx]
    sortedpoly.append(line)
    coords = line[1]

for line in sortedpoly:
    print line
```

Output:

```
>>> ((0, 0), (7, 8))
((7, 8), (1, 2))
((1, 2), (3, 0))
((3, 0), (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Stony Brook algorithm repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/) has a lot of algorithms like this. Here is one that might be of interest for your problem: [Intersection Detection](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/intersection-detection.shtml).